# After adding useDispatch, the code behind cannot be run

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm using `apisauce` to create api for my app. And `apisauce` had a function call `addMonitor`, here: https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce#adding-monitors.

But when I add useDispatch to `naviMonitor`, the code behind cannot run. Specifically, I can't log the `response`. Bellow is my `Api.js`:

```
import apisauce from 'apisauce';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const create = () => {
    ...

    const naviMonitor = (response) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const {status} = response || {};

        if ( (status && status === 200) ) {
            console.log(response);
        } else {
            // TODO
        }
    };

    api.addMonitor(naviMonitor);
}
```

Where was I wrong?

Thank you for help me.

Comment: Looks like you break rules of hooks. Hook should be at top-level in the body of the functional component. What is `create`? Can you provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Comment: So I have to put `const dispatch = useDispatch()` right below the `const create = ()` line?

Comment: Yes, somewhere at the top in the main body, if `create` is a React component. It's difficult to tell for sure with the minute code snippet.

Comment: If you still need more help then I think it would be beneficial to include a more complete code example so we've better context on your use case.

Comment: Is this a component or just a pure function?  You can only call useDispatch inside of a function component, otherwise it breaks the rules of hooks.  If you want to call dispatch from a pure function then you have to get access to dispatch some other way.  Either from your global store instance, or by passing dispatch as an argument to your create function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by returning the response object from API to the component function and use the dispatch method there as we are not allowed to use the useDispatch hook or any react hooks outside the component.

Like :

```
import apisauce from 'apisauce';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const create = () => {
    ...

    const naviMonitor = (response) => {
        
        const {status} = response || {};

        if ( (status && status === 200) ) {
            console.log(response);
            return response; // process response if required.
        } else {
            // TODO
            return response; // process response if required.            
        }
    };

    api.addMonitor(naviMonitor);
}
```

In The component screen:

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const actionHandler = async () => {
        const response = await create();
        dispatch(response);  // dispatch your actions here..
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use that, then every function that needs to call api must do like that?

Comment: from where you are calling the apisauce methods ?

Comment: I call api from redux-saga and custom hook api.

Comment: I mean from where you are calling the saga actions ?

Comment: Ah. My bad, I just want to check the status of the response. If the status is 401, then dispatch actions to logout of the app.

Comment: Have a try by returning the response code if it satisfies your condition then dispatch from the component.